# SCNScene / SCNSphere's visible area

Tags: ios, iphone, scenekit, scnnode, scnsphere

I have a SCNScene that contains a SCNSphere encapsulating the SCNCamera (camera is inside @ center of the SCNSphere, displaying its inner wall on screen).

Is there a method to query or a way to infer / calc the VISIBLE area of this sphere? I dont want the area of the screen in points, or the area of the scene itself, but what the camera is able to render from this sphere in a given device's screen (ipad and iphone do show a different amount of a 360 frame)

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CameraNode.positions just set on the front

```
    cameraRollNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: X)
```

Set sphere material:

```
    sphere_.firstMaterial!.cullMode = SCNCullMode.Front;
```

PIC had two sphere.
HOLP it useful.

[image]